# OAuth2 playground 503 Backend Error while Clear event

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth, oauth2-playground

I tried to clear the primary calendar events from C#:

```
calendarService.Calendars.Clear("primary").Execute();
```

following error was found in google api response:

```
Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Backend Error [503]
Errors [
        Message[Backend Error] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]

]
```

I also tried to check on the Google OAuth2.0 Playground but it gives me following 503 error:

```html
    POST /calendar/v3/calendars/primary/clear HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Content-length: 177
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Mon, 28 Aug 2017 05:52:33 GMT
Vary: Origin, X-Origin
Server: GSE
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Mon, 28 Aug 2017 05:52:33 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,35"
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503, 
    "message": "Backend Error", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Backend Error", 
        "reason": "backendError"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After some googling I tried to retry through Exponential-Backoff algorithm also.
but none of these  works.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/777#issuecomment-235020517), the Google upload servers started timing out on uploads. There may be nothing wrong with your code other than the fact that you are probably just reporting the error rather than handling the error.

> When you get an error like this while using the `.Upload` method, it indicates that the server is too busy to handle your request within the timeout period. Your program should recognize this error and call the `.Resume` method to resume the upload.

Comment: Abielita,

In my account the calendar api response to Get request gives success but when ever I try to clear the primary calendar it show 503 Backend error. I think its not about upload / resume.